# Write back partition being resized

Tags: macos, partitioning, backup, disk-utility

I have problem with my mac it don,t boot. After some research i find out that it mark partition as crashed and want to check it. But while checking it say **invalid sibling link** and can't repair because it's lack of free space.

Now i can only boot from mac os setup disk and use disk utility, terminal etc. So i decided to do following

Using disk utility clone my boot partition to external hdd
Resize it to extend free space 
Check and repair
Resize back to original size
Write back to internal hdd

How do you think is it possible solution?
Also i have a time machine backup but only selected directories not entire hdd. May be i can use that backup in my situation? But i can't find any ways to use it except reinstall mac os and than restore files from backup.

UPD
I back up partition to external HDD and resize it to have more than 50Gb free space. So it can rebuild B-Tree. But i'm unable to resize it back. It say that no free space but i set value according `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/diskXsY limits` and set value bigger than `Minimum size:` it reports.

Comment: You may be able to clear up the disk space issue by following http://one-cheekymonkey.blogspot.com/2013_06_01_archive.html and removing some files.

Comment: Thanks, i was done something similar, it was magically starts up and now i have more than 20 Gb free space but it still can't fix it. Also i was trying to implement my solution that isn't successful either. See my update.